# Does Angular 2+ (Angular 7) have a code diff component

Tags: angularjs, angular

Does Angular 2+ (Angular 7 to be exact) have a code diff component or plugin that can be used for comparing 2 separate text files.

Our current AngularJS app, which we're upgrading, uses Ace-Diff which works well. Yet I can't find anyone who's successfully used an Angular2 version of Ace-Diff, or PrettyDiff, etc.

Comment: I'm confused. `Angular 2+ !== AngularJS 1.7`.

Comment: @DavidWalschots: By Angular 2+ I'm referring to anything post AngularJS. As you probably know, after their first javascript version, the Angular team rewrote their framework to a TextScript / componentized version. I called it Angular 1.7 but I think that's wrong, editing to Angular 7.

Comment: @paiego does this mean the "AngularJS" tag should also be removed since it says it should not be used for versions 2 or later?

Answer (score 2):

You have currently have two options:

1. You use ngx-diff [See npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-diff)
2. You implement your own Component using a 3rd-party-library like [google-diff-match-patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch)

ngx-diff's Fetaures are pretty limited and im not sure how the styling works so you maybe wanna build your own for flexibility.

Be a Hero and publish it to npm so everyone can use it.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has migrated this. I'd love to be the hero but don't have much time for that ;)

Comment: You can still use the google-diff-match-patch as third-party-library in angular.

Comment: I implemented ngx-diff it only has line by line diff. side by side is more readable.. so it has limited features.

Comment: Version [v8.0.0](https://github.com/rars/ngx-diff/releases/tag/v8.0.0) of `ngx-diff` now contains a side-by-side diff.